# Assigning a value to an object gives Type 'string | number | boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: typescript

Given following example code:

```
type Foo = {
  foo: string,
  bar: boolean,
  baz: number
}

private test = () => {
    const foo = { foo: "bar", bar: true, baz: 1 } as Foo
    for (const entries of Object.entries(foo)) {
      const key = entries[0] as keyof Required<Foo>
      const value = entries[1] as Foo[keyof Required<Foo>]
      foo[key] = value // Type 'string | number | boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'
    }
  }
```

Why is the code throwing Type 'string | number | boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'? When all I do is assigning the initial value back to the initial object?

And how to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: This doesn't make any sense: you've got an *empty* object that you are trying to loop over the entries of meaning the loop won't even *run*. Secondly it's not clear at all *why* you would try to construct an object this way instead of using something that the compiler understands like the object spread `...` or some other way that is type safe and doesn't require a bunch of unsafe casts.

Comment: You've told the compiler that `key` is `"foo" | "bar" | "baz"` and that `value` is `string | number | boolean`, and those two types are completely independent union types.  There's no correlation there.  So the compiler is worried they don't match; it's essentially [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) (although your example has got other problems you should clear up). The fix is usually to use generics, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/W4bgeN). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: this is obviously just an example @JaredSmith I tried to make a very simple example out of the complex case I have

Comment: This sound right @jcalz would you mind writing up a solution I can test?

Comment: Can you test [this](https://tsplay.dev/W4bgeN) or not?

Comment: Thank you, the first example does work @jcalz but I’d not call this pretty :D
You can post it and I’ll accept it

Comment: Your example should be *runnable*. From [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):  "Your code examples should... provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem *in the question itself*" (emphasis in the original text).